# I need to replace a line with particular string with contents of another file using c#

Tags: c#, string, list, console-application

I have two files , File1.txt and File2.txt  , I need to replace a particular string in file1 with contents of file2 using C# console application.

**file 1 :**

This is a sample file

..

code-block
..

some text

end of file

**File 2 :**

// some c# code //

i need to replace the string "code-block" with the contents of File 2.

Edit 1:

I had tried to read the file as Array and also as a list

```
var fileContent = File.ReadAllLines(file_path);
            List<string> allLinesText = File.ReadAllLines(file_path).ToList();
            string parentdirectory = Directory.GetParent(Path.GetDirectoryName(file_path)).FullName.ToString(); 

            foreach( var line in fileContent)
            {

                if ( line.Contains("{% code-block %}"))
                {
                    string code_path = line.Replace("{%", string.Empty).Replace("%}", string.Empty).Trim();
                    string code_fullpath = Path.Combine(parentdirectory, code_path);
                    if(File.Exists(code_fullpath))
                    {
                        var code_content = File.ReadAllLines(code_fullpath);
                       // int insert_code_at = 

                     // allLinesText.Insert( allLinesText.IndexOf(line)
                    }
                    
                }
```

Comment: What have you already tried? Did it fail? Why did it fail? Please [edit] your question to answer these questions. For further reading: https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: If you fill the text into the list, is there 1 item in the list or is each word stored as 1 item. Maybe your word can't be found. maybe check it with the debugger.

Comment: I am adding each line of the file as item in the list<string> , but it does not have to be in same way , i just want that particular line of my line to be replaced with contents of another file

Comment: The easy (and safe) way is to read lines from the first file and write them to a temporary output file until the magic line appears, then copy the lines of the lines of the file code-block to the temporary file, and continue until the end of the first file. When finished, delete the first file and rename the temporary file. (It's safe because if it crashes during the process, the first file hasn't been modified. If it crashes during the delete-and-rename, the final data is still in the temporary file.)

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the "magic string" appears exactly once? Or could it be that it does not appear at all or multiple times? What is th eexpected result in these cases?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `String.Replace`. Sample code:

```
string text = File.ReadAllText("file1.txt");
text = text.Replace("text needs to be replaced", "new text");
File.WriteAllText("file1.txt", text);
```